# Delegate touch gesture handling to WebView's content

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, multi-touch

In my WinRT (Metro/Store) XAML-based app I'd like to be able load an external web site in the WebView in a way that would propagate all the touch events (pinch zoom, slide horizontally and vertically) to the web site itself - instead of having the WebView handle them.

I tied to set WebView's `ManipulationMode` to "None".
I tried to set all the `ScrollViewer` properties to "False" or "Disabled".
I even tried to subsribe to WebView's `ManipulationStarting`, `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationCompleted` events (setting `e.Handled = true` for each of them).

`WebView` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) indicates that the current implementation is quite limited, especially in terms of interactivity.
Does the fact that it actually uses IE10 in Document Mode mean that there is no way to reach the original (content) web site's interactivity level?

**Update: mouse gestures (such as click and drag) are working OK, being properly passed on to the web content for handling; it's just the touch interactions that I need to figure out.**

Comment: Have you found how to resolve the problem?

Comment: No, it became irrelevant for me.
It's possible that this works now with the 8.1 version of WebView, but I haven't tried.